# Numpy Where Changing Timestamps/Datetime to Integers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, where-clause

Not so much a question but something puzzling me.

I have a column of dates that looks something like this:

```
0              NaT
1       1996-04-01
2       2000-03-01
3              NaT
4              NaT
5              NaT
6              NaT
7              NaT
8              NaT
```

I'd like to convert it the NaTs to a static value. 
(Assume I imported pandas as pd and numpy as np).

If I do:

```
mydata['mynewdate'] = mydata.mydate.replace(
    np.NaN, pd.datetime(1994,6,30,0,0))
```

All is well, I get:

```
0       1994-06-30
1       1996-04-01
2       2000-03-01
3       1994-06-30
4       1994-06-30
5       1994-06-30
6       1994-06-30
7       1994-06-30
8       1994-06-30
```

But if I do:

```
mydata['mynewdate'] = np.where(
    mydata['mydate'].isnull(), pd.datetime(1994,6,30,0,0),mydata['mydate'])
```

I get:

```
0        1994-06-30 00:00:00
1         828316800000000000
2         951868800000000000
3        1994-06-30 00:00:00
4        1994-06-30 00:00:00
5        1994-06-30 00:00:00
6        1994-06-30 00:00:00
7        1994-06-30 00:00:00
8        1994-06-30 00:00:00
```

This operation converts the original, non-null dates to integers.  I thought there might be a mix-up of data types, so I did this:

```
mydata['mynewdate'] = np.where(
    mydata['mydate'].isnull(), pd.datetime(1994,6,30,0,0),pd.to_datetime(mydata['mydate']))
```

And still get:

```
0        1994-06-30 00:00:00
1         828316800000000000
2         951868800000000000
3        1994-06-30 00:00:00
4        1994-06-30 00:00:00
5        1994-06-30 00:00:00
6        1994-06-30 00:00:00
7        1994-06-30 00:00:00
8        1994-06-30 00:00:00
```

Please note (and don't ask): Yes, I have a better solution for replacing nulls.  This question is not about replacing nulls (as the title indicates that it is not) but how numpy where is handling dates.  I ask because I will have more complex conditions to select dates to replace in the future, and thought numpy where would do the job.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's due to wonky interactions between Numpy's `datetime64`, Pandas' `Timestamp`, and/or `datetime.datetime`.  I fixed it by setting the replacement value to be a `numpy.datetime64` from the start.

```
static_date = np.datetime64('1994-06-30')
# static_date = np.datetime64(pd.datetime(1994, 6, 30))

mydata.assign(
    mynewdate=np.where(
        mydata.mydate.isnull(),
        static_date,
        mydata.mydate
    )
)

      mydate  mynewdate
0        NaT 1994-06-30
1 1996-04-01 1996-04-01
2 2000-03-01 2000-03-01
3        NaT 1994-06-30
4        NaT 1994-06-30
5        NaT 1994-06-30
6        NaT 1994-06-30
7        NaT 1994-06-30
8        NaT 1994-06-30
```

Comment: Cool.  I figured it was something like this.  I hadn't hit upon the correct converting what to what to get this to work.  The straightforward: mydata['mynewdate'] = np.where(mydata['mydate'].isnull(), np.datetime64('1994-06-30'),mydata['mydate']) worked as well.

Comment: @Vaishali: Please note the comment at the end of my post:"Please note (and don't ask): Yes, I have a better solution for replacing nulls. This question is not about replacing nulls (as the title indicates that it is not) but how numpy where is handling dates. I ask because I will have more complex conditions to select dates to replace in the future, and thought numpy where would do the job."

Answer (score 2):

If you are in `pandas` try to using `mask/where` from `pandas`

```
df.mask(df['Date'].isnull(), pd.to_datetime('1994-06-30'))
Out[824]: 
        Date
0 1994-06-30
1 1996-04-01
2 2000-03-01
3 1994-06-30
4 1994-06-30
5 1994-06-30
6 1994-06-30
7 1994-06-30
8 1994-06-30
```

Comment: Thanks. But I like I said, I was asking because I will have some fairly complex conditions to test in the future, and mask is probably not going to cut it.

Answer (score 0):

an option is to use a list comprehension, something like below should work:

```
mydata['mynewdate'] = [pd.datetime(1994,6,30,0,0) if pd.isna(mydata.loc[j,'mydate']) else mydata.loc[j,'mydate'] for j in mydata.index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a very similar problem (I used numpy's `.where()` function, but the issue presents itself the same).  I don't know why this works, but it does (with one caveat explained below):

Original code:

```
df['date']  = np.where(df['date'].between(df['start'], df['end']), df['date'], None)
```

But that resulted in a 'date' column with nanosecond dates (eg. 1656374400000000000)

Updated code:

```
df['date']  = np.where(df['date'].between(df['start'], df['end']), df['date'].astype(str), None)
```

The only difference is the `astype(str)` bit toward the end.  This returned a date in the 'YYYY-mm-dd' format I started with.

The caveat here is that a previous datetime.datetime data type was converted to a string, but it's very easy to convert back, and I could have even done it in-line by wrapping the whole thing in a `pd.to_datetime()` function, but for clarity, left it out here.

Comment: I'm no sure this adds much to the original 5 year old question.  `pandas` has changed since then (e.g `pd.datetime` no longer works).  At the very least you need to be clear what `df['date']` contains, `dtype`, and if objects, what types.  There are many ways of expressing dates, in python, numpy and pandas.  A useful answer would help us match those ways consistently, not just give us another (confusing) mix.