# for-loop over df converts datetime to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": ['2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 08:52:00', 
                            '2020-04-09 08:52:00', '2020-04-09 08:52:00', '2020-04-09 16:03:00', '2020-04-10 06:50:00', 
                            '2020-04-10 06:50:00', '2020-04-10 12:33:00', '2020-04-10 12:33:00'],
                  "ID": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
    
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'])
```

Output:

```
                   Time ID
0   2020-04-09 06:46:00 1
1   2020-04-09 06:46:00 1
2   2020-04-09 06:46:00 1
3   2020-04-09 08:52:00 1
4   2020-04-09 08:52:00 1
5   2020-04-09 08:52:00 1
6   2020-04-09 16:03:00 2
7   2020-04-10 06:50:00 2
8   2020-04-10 06:50:00 2
9   2020-04-10 12:33:00 2
10  2020-04-10 12:33:00 2
```

Now i want to create a new `df_event`, that lists the different `ID`s with the associated `Time` (`min()`). But when I execute the following for loop:

```
df_event = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Time'])

t = df['ID'].unique()
df_event['ID']=t
for item in t:
    df_sub=df[df.ID == item]
    df_event['Time']=np.where(df_event['ID']==item,df_sub.Time.min(), df_event['Time'])
    
df_event
```

the first entry is output as int and not as datetime:

```
   ID                  Time
0   1   1586414760000000000
1   2   2020-04-09 16:03:00
```

With more than one entry, the problem occurs only on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your code, by creating `df_event` this way:

```
df_event = df.groupby("ID").min().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ID  Time
0   1   2020-04-09 06:46:00
1   2   2020-04-09 16:03:00
```

If you want to keep using `np.where()`, the problem seems to come from compatibility problems between types with pandas and numpy. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52430395/numpy-where-changing-timestamps-datetime-to-integers) may help.

Comment: First thanks for your answer! By trying to use `groupby`, i got this error `f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Comment: It is weird. By executing your first block of code and then the line I gave, I have the result shown above. Maybe other variables are interfering. You can also try to remove `.reset_index()`, which is optional.

Comment: hmm. thats weird. I delete the `'Time'` in the `min()` and now it works..

Comment: Yes, the `'Time'` was useless. It must raise an error on some versions.